# Executing Commands Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to execute a command by the click of a button, and *not* when the page loads.

```
function hey() {
  alert('bla');
}
```

Do I add something to the code above or to the button?

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="hey()" />
```

Comment: Yes, I think you do need to add something.

Comment: I don't mean to insult you, but based on the wording of your question and supporting information, I would say it sure seems you need to spend more time reading about javascript and html. jquery would also be something to look into.

Answer (score 5):

Have you taken the time to type in your question into the magical Google box yet? Surely you'll see something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me, now" onclick="hey()" />
```

Comment: Yes I have a button like this but the function still executed when the page loads

Comment: Post the rest of your code. Nothing should be happening when the page loads.

Comment: Yep, I see it. There should be a `<body onload="">` somewhere as well.

Comment: PLEASE dont tell me 'have i taken the time or more effort please because I have googled this, I have added the button in html but the function was still being loaded when the page loaded, that why I asked the question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aVjpY/ <-- example showes it waits for you to push the button. Its not executing while page is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have the function that alerts a window to the user.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMe() {
        alert('You clicked on the button');
    }
</script>

<button onclick="showMe()">Button</button>
```

This will make sure that the function is only called when the button is clicked upon and not when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have a code that should work for alerting something on the click of a button. But you state that the code is running on page load. You have to check you code, looking for:

- An `onload` attribute on the body tag, something like `<body onload="hey()">`
- A call to hey somewhere else on your js code. Look for `hey()`.
- Maybe a reference to the button followed by a call to `.click()`

There is something else on your code causing the function to be called, you'll have to scan your code to find out what it is.